# TransactionScope with MySQL and Distributed Transactions

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions, mysql-connector, transactionscope

I have an ASP.Net WebAPI instance setup that uses a MySQL database for storage.  I have written an `ActionFilter` that handles creating a `TransactionScope` for the lifetime of a single endpoint request.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(
    HttpActionContext actionContext,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    var transactionScopeOptions = new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted };
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, transactionScopeOptions, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        var handledTask = await continuation();

        transaction.Complete();

        return handledTask;
    }
}
```

Then throughout the endpoints I have different queries/commands that open/close connections using the `autoenlist=true` functionality of `DbConnection`'s.  An example endpoint may be:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateStuffAsync()
{
    var query = this.queryService.RetrieveAsync();

    // logic to do stuff

    var update = this.updateService.Update(query);

    return this.Ok();
}
```

I don't create a single `DbConnection` and pass it around from the top, as this is a simplistic example, when in practise passing the connection between services would require a large refactor (although if necessary, this can be done).  I also read that it is better to open/close the connections as necessary (i.e. keep them open for as little time as possible).  The `queryService` and `updateService` open/close `DbConnection`'s via `using` statements:

```
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient");
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=user;Password=password;Connect Timeout=300;AutoEnlist=true;";

    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }

    var result = await connection.QueryAsync(Sql).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return result;
}
```

The same `DbConnection` is generally not used for multiple queries within the same API endpoint request -- but the same connection string is.

Intermittently I am seeing an exception thrown when attempting to open the connection:

```
"ExceptionType": "System.NotSupportedException",
"ExceptionMessage": "System.NotSupportedException: MySQL Connector/Net does not currently support distributed transactions.\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction transaction)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()"
```

I do not understand why it is attempting to escalate the transaction to a distributed transaction, when all of the connections are against the same database.  Or am I misunderstanding/misusing the `TransactionScope` and `DbConnection` instances?

Comment: Bradly Grainger is correct. It works well. I use another MySQL Connection instead of MySqlConnection. I guess that MySqlConnection is not developed anymore by Oracle. I confirmed that https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/ can resolve your problem. Please try it.

Answer (score 5):

The `System.Transactions.Transaction` object makes the determination of whether to escalate to a distributed transaction based on how many separate "resource managers" (e.g., a database) have enlisted in the transaction.

It does not draw a distinction between connections to different physical databases (that do require a distributed transaction) and multiple `MySqlConnection` connections that have the same connection string and connect to the same database (which might not). (It would be very difficult for it to determine that two separate "resource managers" ① represent the same physical DB and ② are being used sequentially, not in parallel.) As a result, when multiple `MySqlConnection` objects enlist in a transaction, it will always escalate to a distributed transaction.

When this happens, you run into [MySQL bug #70587](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70587) that distributed transactions aren't supported in Connector/NET.

Workarounds would be:

1. Make sure only one `MySqlConnection` object is opened within any `TransactionScope`.
2. Change to a separate connector that does support distributed transactions. You could use MySqlConnector ([NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), [GitHub](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector)) as a drop-in replacement for Connector/NET. I've heard that [dotConnect for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/) supports them also (but haven't tried that one).